# How to claim the existency of such an extension here?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, dual-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a completely regular space (**Definition**: all singletons are closed and points and closed sets can be separated by continuous maps) and $K$ be a compact subset of $X$ and $g \in C(K)$ ($:=$ the space of continous fucntions on $K$); then **does there exists a continuous extension**, $\bar{g}:X \to \Bbb{C}$, of $g$?? It seems that this thing has been used in the following proof (screenshot attached):
[image]

Here $X$ is not given to be "normal" so we cannot use "Tietze's exttension theorem". Then how did the author claim the existency of such extension there?

Comment: See proof of the theorem 2 [here](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/tietze-urysohn-like-theorems-for-completely-regular-spaces/#:~:text=Tietze's%20extension%20theorem%20indicates%20that,extended%20to%20the%20entire%20space.) The point is every completely regular space can be embedded in a product of closed unit intervals which is normal.

Comment: @Sumanta Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See theorem 2 [here](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/tietze-urysohn-like-theorems-for-completely-regular-spaces/): we do have such a theorem for a **compact** subset in a completely regular space ( so quite close to normal); it’s the best we can achieve.